# How to merge two JS objects

Tags: javascript

I have a JS object lets say json 1

```
[
    {
        "id": "123",
        "testname": "test123",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "active": true,
        "type": "test6"
    }

 {
        "id": "456",
        "testname": "test564",
        "name": "Ship Therasus",
        "active": true,
        "type": "test7"
    }

.... some 100 entries 
]
```

and json 2 some like below

```
[
    {
        "id": "123",
        "country": "USA",
        "state": "KA",
        "age": 24,
        "group": "g1"
    }

 {
        "id": "456",
        "country": "UK",
        "state": "MA",
        "age": 28,
        "group": "G2"
    }

...... 100 entries
]
```

Now Id is the constant thing between json1 and json2 I want to make a resultant object something like below lets call json3. I want to match the id and get country and state from json2 and append to json 1 .How can i do this using JavaScript?

```
[
    {
        "id": "123",
        "testname": "test123",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "active": true,
        "type": "test6",
        "country":"USA",
         "state":"KA"
    }

 {
        "id": "456",
        "testname": "test564",
        "name": "Ship Therasus",
        "active": true,
        "type": "test7",
         "country":"UK",
         "state":"MA"
    }
]
```

Comment: If you can rely on array indices that are matching, you could take a simply place these two arrays as elements in a third array and use Underscore's `.zip` function or implement something similar. http://underscorejs.org/#zip

Comment: Are the elements in the same order for both arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note :** If you do prefer *jQuery*.

Using ***$.extend()*** you can merge one or more objects into the first one. There are many ways to use *$.extend()* that solves different scenarios. Your's matches the following one where you have two objects with some common and different properties. As you want to merge both of them into one object and you also want all the uncommon properties of both objects to be there you need to do it like this,

```
var firstData = [
    {
        "id": "123",
        "testname": "test123",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "active": true,
        "type": "test6"
    },

    {
        "id": "456",
        "testname": "test564",
        "name": "Ship Therasus",
        "active": true,
        "type": "test7"
    }
];

var secondData = [
    {
        "id": "123",
        "country": "USA",
        "state": "KA",
        "age": 24,
        "group": "g1"
    },

 {
        "id": "456",
        "country": "UK",
        "state": "MA",
        "age": 28,
        "group": "G2"
    }
];

// This will remove the properties that you don't want to be in the merged object
$.each(secondData, function(index, object){
    $.each(object, function(key, value){
        if(key == "age"){
            delete secondData[index][key];
        }
        else if(key == "group"){
            delete secondData[index][key];
        }
    });
});

// this is to merge the objects
$.extend(true, firstData, secondData);

// check your console
console.log(firstData);
```

What ***.extend()*** does is merge both object and keep it in the first object. The first argument *true* specifies that the object will be recursively merged.

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/d5rv0n3f/)

**References :** [***$.extend()***](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)

Comment: OP wants using Javascript not jQuery

Comment: Do the objects in the two arrays need to be in the same order?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jQuery, you can do it like this:

```
var json1 = [{id:1, one: 1}, {id:2, one: 2}];
var json2 = [{id:1, two: 1}, {id:2, two: 2}];

var merged = $.map(json1, function(v1, i) {
  var result = $.extend({}, v1);
  var v2s = $.grep(json2, function(v2) {
    return v2.id === v1.id;
  });
  for (var i = v2s.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    $.extend(result, v2s[i]);
  };
  return result;
});
```

---

non jQuery version:

```
var merged = [];
for (var i = json1.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var v1 = json1[i];
  var result = {};
  for (var key in v1) {
    if (v1.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      result[key] = v1[key];
    }
  }
  for (var j = json2.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
    var v2 = json2[j];
    if (v1.id === v2.id) {
      for (var key in v2) {
        if (v2.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          result[key] = v2[key];
        }
      }
    }
  }
  merged.push(result);
};
```